# How to make an executable file out of start-tor-browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

After extracting the tor-browser.tar.xz, I found there are two things in the tor-
browser folder. One is a Browser folder and the other is a start-tor-browser 
file, which I used to be able to open as a executable file in Linux Mint, but this 
time I was on Ubuntu. How can I make start-tor-browser an executable file to start Tor Browser with, so that I don't need to launch the Tor Browser using the terminal every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line you can make the file executable by running:

```
chmod +x start-tor-browser.sh
```

(where `start-tor-browser.sh` is the name of the start script, which I can't remember off the top of my head).

In Ubuntu you can tell Nautilus to run the script instead of opening it in Gedit by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus) from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I do as what you say, but nothing change, I still need to launch the tor browser using terminal. Can you provide me another way to solve this problem ?

Comment: What is happening when you attempt to double click on the start-tor-browser script? Can you provide more information?

Comment: It will be opened by gedit, and if I choose to open it using terminal, there would be nothing happen. BTW, the way I launch tor browser before using terminal is to open a terminal,and use "cd" command to get into the tor directory, and type "./star-tor-browser" to launch tor browser.

Comment: Updated with a link to this question on Ask Ubuntu (this question really has nothing to do with Tor, but we can leave it here as it may help other people in future).